# Подсветка элементов. internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer

Подскажите как включить подсветку элементов (если это возможно) в internet explorer 11.
Например как в хроме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажми на эту кнопку которая обведена на фото (квадрат)

[image: фото]